# Mixed-up quotations

Tags: wordplay

I was looking up some quotations the other day by a famous person.  The following three quotations were all made by the same person, but somehow they got mixed up before I could read them.

Can you tell me what happened to them, what the quotations are, and who said them?

**Quotation 1**

> *The sis maize imp puller ill legion.  They risen own eat fort dimples; known eat fork ump lick hated fill us if he.  A rowin' bray, now roan art a sour temp pull. Duff ill us iffy ask eye and nest.*

**Quotation 2**

> *Harp rhyme purr puss sin thus lie fist ooh hell paw thirds. Sand diff few can tell path emmett leased owned heard dumb.*

**Quotation 3**

> *Weak enough fur robed hay imp ease sin theatre whorl dent ill owe he may cap ease withers elves.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1:

> "This is my simple religion. There is no need for temples; no need for complicated philosophy. Our own brain, our own heart is our temple; the philosophy is kindness."

2:

> "Our prime purpose in this life is to help others. And if you can't help them, at least don't hurt them."

3:

> "We can never obtain peace in the outer world until we make peace with ourselves."

These are all quotes from

> the Dalai Lama.

and they've been modified

> by taking phonetically similar words.

Comment: He also asked for what happened to them, otherwise this answer seems correct

Comment: This is good enough. I was looking for some explanation like "oral transcription error," but you got the gist of it.

Comment: anyone can wreck a nice beach :-) - from an ad for Dragon IIRC