# Famous quotes transcribed wrong

Tags: english

Someone was listening to a bunch of famous quotes, but they wrote them down wrong! Figure out which ones they were listening to! They may not have written the whole quote. (not sure if the english tag is correct, feel free to change it).

Toby Arnott: "Toby".

Force Corin save any ursa go

Hear slow king gat Uke id

Toad eh? Icon cider mice elf the locky East Manon, thieve ace off they hearth.

Comment: I think this could have been a little more creative and challenging. I did not even need to read it to the end before I knew the way to solve it -  It's not exactly the same, but see [this](http://www.mrc-cbu.cam.ac.uk/people/matt.davis/cmabridge/) for why this puzzle is so easy.

Comment: Very similar to [this question](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24286).  Not sure if it would be considered a duplicate, though...

Comment: @JonathanAllan How does the linked article relate to this puzzle?

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain - only an example that it's pretty easy to read things that are close in form in one way or another and that there may be ways to make a similar puzzle that would be more challenging; it's what sprang to mind when I had the method before I'd finished scanning the question.

Comment: @JonathonAllen the spillnegs are toltaly deffiernt tahn the way the qoutes are slleped :). It's only the sounds that are similar. I admit it was easy, but I've heard over and over again that an easy puzzle is not necessarily a bad puzzle.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain it is very similar, but they are different quote, so I do not think it is a duplicate. And just so you know, I may have viewed that puzzle when you posted it, but I have no recollection of doing so.

Comment: @RichardRoe, yes I know - I did not vote to close, and yes it *is* a puzzle. I am merely pointing out that it was extremely easy (and what I think makes it so) - as I said it's not exactly the reason in that article, but it's a similar property (my spelling is absolutely awful by the way, maybe that's why I find it such a similar property?).

Comment: Re: reasons this is not particularly difficult... [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anguish_Languish) is what sprang to mind for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Toby

> To be or not to be

Force

> Four score and seven years ago

Hear

> Here's looking at you, kid

Toad

> Today I consider myself the luckiest man on the face of the earth

Answer (score 5):

Toby Arnott: "Toby".

> To be or not to be?

Force Corin save any ursa go

> Four score and seven years ago

Hear slow king gat Uke id

> Here's looking at you, kid

Toad eh? Icon cider mice elf the locky East Manon, thieve ace off they hearth.

> Today I consider myself the luckiest man on the face of the earth.

Comment: Woo, beat you by 38 seconds! :P